# Bluebird promise: loop over mongoose result

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bluebird

I query author data from a MongoDB via Mongoose (MEAN environment). The author data also contains an array of books that the author wrote (-> results.books). Once received, I'd like to iterate through this array of books and check for certain values. This is my code so far.

```
return Author.findOne({_id: req.user._id}, '-username').execAsync()
.then(function(results) {

return Promise.each(results.books) //this line causes TypeError rejection
}).then(function(book){     
   console.log('book:'+book); // test output
   if(book==='whatever‘){
      //do foo
   }  
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log('Error: '+err);
});
```

Unfortunately I can't get it to work as it keeps giving me a rejection TypeError for the line marked above. I tried to apply this solution here ([Bluebird Promisfy.each, with for-loops and if-statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110099/bluebird-promisfy-each-with-for-loops-and-if-statements)) but it wouldn't work out as it also seems to be a different kind of problem.

Comment: Does findOne really return an array? I don't know it - but guess that you get an object back, but `each` expects an array

Comment: Per [doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html), a potentially-null single document should returned by `findOne`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bluebird's `Promise.each()` takes an iterable AND a iterator callback function that will be called for each item in the iterable.  You are not passing the callback function.  The `.then()` handler after `Promise.each()` is called when the entire iteration is done.  It looks like you're expecting that to be the iterator - that's not the case.

Bluebird doc for `Promise.each()` is [here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html).

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but perhaps this is what you want:

```
return Author.findOne({_id: req.user._id}, 'username').execAsync()
   .then(function (results) {
        return Promise.each(results.books, function(book) {
            console.log('book:' + book); // test output
            if (book === 'whatever‘) {
               //do foo
            }
        });
    }).then(function() {
        // Promise.each() is done here
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    });
```

Comment: that seems to work. Thanks! I guess, I need to get back and do a bit more of reading on promises to get a deeper understanding, still struggling with basic issues - bummer. Thanks again.

Comment: One more thing: is there any way to quit the .each() loop early (before end of array is reached) except by throwing an exception? Something comparable to 'break;' in while loops or a plain 'return;' counterpart? Couldn't find anything in the Bluebird doc.

Comment: @IgorP. - I'm not aware of any way to quit early other than throwing or returning a rejected promise - both of which will cause the returned promise to be rejected.